# Realtek RTL8188CE wireless not working on Toshiba Satelite L655-s5153

Tags: 11.10, wireless, realtek, toshiba-satellite

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 however my wireless is not working. I cant find a guide to fix this specifically for my
Toshiba Satelite L655-s5153 .

Can someone please guide me step by step in how to find a simple solution to this as I am not tech
savy by any means? Any help will be appreciated. I am using RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter

Answer (score 1):

[How to install Realtek RTL8188CE WiFi drivers](http://www.chayx.net/2011/06/how-to-install-realtek-rtl8188ce-wifi-drivers-thinkpad-edge-13-on-ubuntu-natty-1104.html)

The link is for Lenovo ThinkPad Edge laptops but works just as well for Toshiba if followed, the essences are the same.

[Realtek Homepage](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CE)